# Object not "allowed in Chatter Groups" is not searchable

Tags: search, summer-15, visibility, global-search

I have a custom object, with a custom tab defined, and Global Search enabled.

The object and tab visibility are all so that I should be able to search records of that object using the global search, but I can't - the object does not appear in the search results. The object describe too has an .isSearchable() value of false.

But if I allow the object in Chatter Groups ([this new option](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000214528&language=en_US) added in SU15) I am able to search the object.

This is undocumented behavior AFAIK, I've tried to look around but there's nothing that links this option to Search feature. I wanted to share to hear if anyone has met the same problem or I'm missing something out.